# Facebook API - webcam FBML

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk, webcam

What is the FBML tag or any other option (I mean in API) to take photo from a webcam in Facebook (and next upload it to my profile)? I can see such an option in my profile, but I don't know how to use it in Facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option (as far as I know). In any case FBML will be deprecated on June 6, 2012. You will have to look into the video API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#videos.

There are examples on the Facebook Developers' blog of how to achieve this

- [Using the Graph API to upload Video](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/)
- [Uploading Videos to an Application, Group, or Page via the Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/515/)